# Java Swing DatePicker like extjs/eyecon like style TopYear panel and month chooser panel

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

Anybody have using a java swing date picker/ date chooser / calendar component for selecting date from JTextField/JCombobox component. This component behave extjs/eyecon like style, TopPanel for year selection and month panel for selecting month. Anyone have used or created these 3 Navigation panels on calendar component.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [JXDatePicker](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html) from the SwingLabs, SwingX libraries

Comment: Thanks. But I am seeking extjs like three panel (top/middle/front) layout, because that's easy to select long range of date like year 2050 or 1954 easily.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot? All the examples I can find look like the JXDatePicker

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:datepicker  like this.. when I click on Month Year(February 2013), we can see month and year

Comment: http://calendarcontrolinjavafx.blogspot.in/2012/01/calendar-control-in-javafx-20.html  . Got Inspiration from this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be useful for you

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/datePicker.html

Comment: Thanks. Seeking distant range at quickly for choosing date of birth like May 12, 1985 quickly.

Comment: [check it out](http://www.cwroethel.com/Projects/JPopupCalendar/Docs/Documentation.jsp?topic=QuickStart)

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/     and   http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:datepicker

Comment: http://calendarcontrolinjavafx.blogspot.in/2012/01/calendar-control-in-javafx-20.html  . Thanks I am trying to study and convert this to swing.